# Ответ клиенту StreamWriter

Tags: c#, сокет, потоки-данных, сокеты

Мне необходимо отправить ответ клиенту после подключении 1 байт. Клиент подключается, по мануалу, после подключения, я должен отправить ответ в виде одного байта(0x01), после отправки мне ничего не приходит. Правильно ли я делаю, вот код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Receiver();
    }

    public static void Receiver()
    {
        byte answer = 0x01;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter port :");
        int port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        server.Start();


        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений... ");

            // получаем входящее подключение
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент. Выполнение запроса...");

            StreamReader st = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.Default);
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            sr.AutoFlush = true;

            string answerFromBlock;

            while (client.Connected)
            {
                answerFromBlock = st.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(answerFromBlock))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ответ от блока: {0}", answerFromBlock);
                    sr.Write(answer);

                    string path = "logs.txt";

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                    {
                        writer.AutoFlush = true;
                        writer.WriteLine(answerFromBlock);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Ожидание новых данных.");
                }
            }
        } while (true);

    }
}
```

Клиент - это GPS блок на автомобиле. Мой первый опыт отправки или получения данных.

Comment: так синхронно написано...(может лучше делать через события и/или Task?); не видел чтобы server использовался где-то кроме создания клиента.

Comment: @dgzargo синхронно для тестов, не нужно пока больше соединений держать.

Comment: я не понимаю: сервер должен САМ отправить ответ когда присылаешь 0x01?

Comment: @dgzargo нет, когда блок подключился, на блок надо отправить 1 байт. Блок подключается, первым его сообщением приходить его идентификатор, после его сообщения я отправляю ему сразу 1 байт, после этого он должен начать слать новые сообщения с инфо о координатах, но он молчит, по этому я задал сюда вопрос что бы убедится что я правильно все написал.

Comment: напиши подробнее как все должно происходить (предыдущий комментарий запутывает). желательно исправь вопрос